# Python web programming

Tags: python, cherrypy

Good morning.

As the title indicates, I've got some questions about using python for web development.

- What is the best setup for a development environment, more specifically, what webserver to use, how to bind python with it. Preferably, I'd like it to be implementable in both, *nix and win environment.

My major concern when I last tried apache + mod_python + CherryPy was having to reload webserver to see the changes. Is it considered normal? For some reason cherrypy's autoreload didn't work at all.

- What is the best setup to deploy a working Python app to production and why? I'm now using lighttpd for my PHP web apps, but how would it do for python compared to nginx for example?
- Is it worth diving straight with a framework or to roll something simple of my own? I see that Django has got quite a lot of fans, but I'm thinking it would be overkill for my needs, so I've started looking into CherryPy.
- How exactly are Python apps served if I have to reload httpd to see the changes? Something like a permanent process spawning child processes, with all the major file includes happening on server start and then just lazy loading needed resources?
- Python supports multithreading, do I need to look into using that for a benefit when developing web apps? What would be that benefit and in what situations?

Big thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here are my thoughts about it:

I am using [Python Paste](http://pythonpaste.org/) for developing my app and eventually also running it (or any other python web server). I am usually not using mod_python or mod_wsgi as it makes development setup more complex.

I am using [zc.buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout) for managing my development environment and all dependencies together with [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). This gives me an isolated sandbox which does not interfere with any Python modules installed system wide.

For deployment I am also using buildout/virtualenv, eventually with a different buildout.cfg. I am also using [Paste Deploy](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/) and it's configuration mechanism where I have different config files for development and deployment.

As I am usually running paste/cherrypy etc. standalone I am using Apache, NGINX or maybe just a Varnish alone in front of it. It depends on what configuration options you need. E.g. if no virtual hosting, rewrite rules etc. are needed, then I don't need a full featured web server in front. When using a web server I usually use ProxyPass or some more complex rewriting using mod_rewrite.

The Python web framework I use at the moment is [repoze.bfg](http://static.repoze.org/bfgdocs/) right now btw.

As for your questions about reloading I know about these problems when running it with e.g. mod_python but when using a standalone "paster serve ... -reload" etc. it so far works really well. repoze.bfg additionally has some setting for automatically reloading templates when they change. If the framework you use has that should be documented.

As for multithreading that's usually used then inside the python web server. As CherryPy supports this I guess you don't have to worry about that, it should be used automatically. You should just eventually make some benchmarks to find out under what number of threads your application performs the best.

Hope that helps.

Comment: glad I could help but of course I am also still learning/experimenting with the best way to do it. And I should add that repoze.bfg also builds on WSGI. There is also lots of useful middleware, like Paste#evalerror, repoze.errorlog, repoze.profiler etc.

Answer (score 8):

**What is the best setup for a development environment?**

Doesn't much matter.  We use Django, which runs in Windows and Unix nicely.  For production, we use Apache in Red Hat.

**Is having to reload webserver to see the changes considered normal?**

Yes.  Not clear why you'd want anything different.  Web application software shouldn't be dynamic.  Content yes.  Software no.

In Django, we *develop* without using a web server of any kind on our desktop.  The Django "runserver" command reloads the application under most circumstances.  For development, this works great.  The times when it won't reload are when we've damaged things so badly that the app doesn't properly.

**What is the best setup to deploy a working Python app to production and why?**

"Best" is undefined in this context.  Therefore, please provide some qualification for "nest" (e.g., "fastest", "cheapest", "bluest")

**Is it worth diving straight with a framework or to roll something simple of my own?**

Don't waste time rolling your own.  We use Django because of the built-in admin page that we don't have to write or maintain.  Saves mountains of work.

**How exactly are Python apps served if I have to reload httpd to see the changes?**

Two methods:

- Daemon - mod_wsgi or mod_fastcgi have a Python daemon process to which they connect.  Change your software.  Restart the daemon.
- Embedded - mod_wsgi or mod_python have an embedded mode in which the Python interpreter is inside the mod, inside Apache.  You have to restart httpd to restart that embedded interpreter.

**Do I need to look into using multi-threaded?**

Yes and no.  Yes you do need to be aware of this.  No, you don't need to do very much.  Apache and mod_wsgi and Django should handle this for you.

Comment: Very clear and helpful. About having to reload the server.. I guess I developed a wrong mindset over the years with PHP, you know, sort of type - check browser, repeat. Not sure how easy it would be to develop without constantly checking the result in the browser, any tips?

Comment: In Django we don't develop with a web serever.  The Django "runserver" command creates a usable web server and reloads the application for us.  Great for development.

Comment: Indeed, I think for development mode it's very very useful to have an automatic reload. For the live stage of course not anymore. But with e.g. paster you can do both, "paster server my.ini" or "paster server my.ini --reload".

Comment: +1: nice clarity (as usual). I still love auto-loading for live sites because I'm running 6 django sites, 1 ruby, 2 php and I hate for all of them to be restarted.

Comment: @Van Gale: Auto-load might be nice.  I don't have a lot of confidence in it, however.  Your experience may be more positive than mine.

Answer (score 6):

+1 to MrTopf's answer, but I'll add some additional opinions.

**Webserver**

Apache is the webserver that will give you the most configurability. Avoid mod_python because it is basically unsupported.  On the other hand, [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) is very well supported and gives you better stability (in other words, easier to configure for cpu/memory usage to be stable as opposed to spikey and unpredictable).

Another huge benefit, you can configure mod_wsgi to reload your application if the wsgi application script is touched, no need to restart Apache.  For development/testing servers you can even configure mod_wsgi to reload when any file in your application is changed.  This is so helpful I even run Apache+mod_wsgi on my laptop during development.

Nginx and lighttpd are commonly used for webservers, either by serving Python apps directly through a fastCGI interface (don't bother with any WSGI interfaces on these servers yet) or by using them as a front end in front of Apache.  Calls into the app get passed through (by proxy) to Apache+mod_wsgi and then nginx/lighttpd serve the static content directly.

Nginx has the added advantage of being able to serve content directly from memcached if you want to get that sophisticated.  I've heard disparaging comments about lighttpd and it does seem to have some development problems, but there are certainly some big companies using it successfully.

**Python stack**

At the lowest level you can program to WSGI directly for the best performance.  There are lots of helpful WSGI modules out there to help you in areas you don't want to develop yourself.  At this level you'll probably want to pick third-party WSGI components to do things like URL resolving and HTTP request/response handling.  A great request/response component is [WebOb](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/).

If you look at [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) you can see their idea of "best-of-breed" WSGI components and a framework that makes it easier than Django to choose your own components like templating engine.

Django might be overkill but I don't think that's a really good argument against.  Django makes the easy stuff easier.  When you start to get into very complicated applications is where you really need to look at moving to lower level frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Google App Engine.  From their website:

> Google App Engine lets you run your
>   web applications on Google's
>   infrastructure. App Engine
>   applications are easy to build, easy
>   to maintain, and easy to scale as your
>   traffic and data storage needs grow.
>   With App Engine, there are no servers
>   to maintain: You just upload your
>   application, and it's ready to serve
>   your users.
>
> You can serve your app using a free
>   domain name on the appspot.com domain,
>   or use Google Apps to serve it from
>   your own domain. You can share your
>   application with the world, or limit
>   access to members of your
>   organization.
>
> App Engine costs nothing to get
>   started. Sign up for a free account,
>   and you can develop and publish your
>   application for the world to see, at
>   no charge and with no obligation. A
>   free account can use up to 500MB of
>   persistent storage and enough CPU and
>   bandwidth for about 5 million page
>   views a month.

Best part of all: It includes Python support, including Django.  Go to http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't feel like getting my apps locked in some vendor platform and make them completely unportable without rewrite.

Comment: You asked what the best setup was... google's infrastructure is the best.  Their free plan has enough bandwidth and cpu for 5 million page views a month...

Answer (score 1):

When you use `mod_python` on a threaded Apache server (the default on Windows), CherryPy runs in the same process as Apache. In that case, you almost certainly **don't** want CP to restart the process.

Solution: use `mod_rewrite` or `mod_proxy` so that CherryPy runs in its own process. Then you can autoreload to your heart's content. :)